# Rubik's cube invalid state? Yellow cross starts with odd number of edges

Tags: rubiks-cube

In solving a Rubik's cube, I've been following the standard beginner instructions. I'm now trying to get the "yellow cross" step done (on the blue side, because I started with solving green), but I think the cube might be in an invalid state. Instead of having 0, 2, or 4 edges of the cross, I can only get an odd number of edges (currently 1, but I while ago it had 3). Here's what the blue side looks like right now:

[image]

Is this solvable?

For reference, here's the other side:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an invalid state. First you need to complete the two layers starting from green.

In the second picture, there are two blocks in the second layer which are not correctly solved. First solve them, and confirm that first and second layers are correct. After this, try the yellow cross step with the blue layer.

Comment: Got lost in the middle and completely forgot I had to finish that step before starting the cross. Back in a normal state now, thanks!